# Best way to add static routes to every pod in a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have 3 nodes running several `OpenVPN pods`, each pod has a VPN network of `100.70.0.0/16`, and clients that connect to these pods receive IP addresses in this range, for example, let's say that client `100.70.162.91` connected to one of the pods.

Now, I want to add more pods running different services on this cluster, and each pod must be able to talk to every VPN client. One of the big steps of the way I would do this so far, using AWS ECS, is adding a route such as `ip route add 100.70.192.91/32 via <OpenVPN-pod-IPv4>/32` on the cluster VPC's subnet route table once a client connects using the AWS API, this method does seem to also work using `docker-compose` and `Kubernetes` as long as all the pods are on the same network.

However, now that I am trying to migrate from ECS to Kubernetes, I cannot seem to find any way to add cluster-wide network static routes on Kubernetes.

What would be the best way to implement this on Kubernetes?

Comment: Don't do this. Use [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) or equal reverse proxy programs.

Answer (score 0):

if your use the vanilla k8s instead of ECS you have an option to add such routes  on worker nodes. So pod traffic to non-k8s (VPN clients network is differ from k8s pods net) networks would egress via worker nodes routing table. You need add static route to VPN clients network on worker nodes.
The route destination you set vpn-pod IP. It is accessible from any k8s worker node.